# Scroll back to top in iOS UITextView after change of text

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView. The text in the view keeps changing based on user action. On many occasions, the text is too large to fit and so my text view (which has a desired fixed width and height) scrolls the text. The control flow is something like this
1) user takes some action, and text view appears with some text (possibly more than what can fit, so comes with a scroll)
2) user dismisses the view (I simply hide the text view)
3) user another action, and text view appears with new text (i use UITextView setText to reassign the text, and simply turn the hidden property to NO)

Problem Scenario:
Perform step 1 above, user scroll down a little to read the content, then proceeds with step 2 and 3. But when the text view reappears, the view is still scrolled a little from the last interaction. I want the text to be visible from the start, meaning, the scroll shud be "reset"

What I tried:

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,0)]; //OR
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,600)]; //600 being an approximate number of characters that can show in my text view after which they flow out and it has to be scrolled.
```

this was the most successful attempt. Worked most of the time, except, sometimes, intermittently, there would be a lot of extra space on top of my line 1 of the text, like someone scrolled/swiped it down and froze it there.

PS:My text cannot be edited by the user. It is always reset to a different string in code